# Decompiling dll file to extract a function (subroutine)

Tags: ida, decompile

I have a university project, and my professor gave me a DLL file which I need to extract a subroutine from, and it is not clearly defined as a subroutine. The purpose is to translate the code to C++ or C.

I opened the code with IDA Pro and searched for the name `acalcul`:

```
CODE:00470C9C aCalcul:                                ; DATA XREF: CODE:00470C0F↑o
CODE:00470C9C                 text "UTF-16LE", 'calcul',0
CODE:00470CAA                 align 4
CODE:00470CAC
CODE:00470CAC loc_470CAC:                             ; CODE XREF: CODE:0047094C↑j
CODE:00470CAC                 push    ebp
CODE:00470CAD                 mov     ebp, esp
CODE:00470CAF                 push    ebx
CODE:00470CB0                 push    esi
CODE:00470CB1                 push    edi
CODE:00470CB2                 push    dword ptr [ebp+8]
CODE:00470CB5                 xor     eax, eax
CODE:00470CB7                 push    ebp
CODE:00470CB8                 push    offset loc_470CDC
CODE:00470CBD                 push    dword ptr fs:[eax]
CODE:00470CC0                 mov     fs:[eax], esp
CODE:00470CC3                 mov     eax, ds:off_474634
CODE:00470CC8                 mov     eax, [eax]
CODE:00470CCA                 mov     edx, [ebp+0Ch]
CODE:00470CCD                 mov     [edx], eax
CODE:00470CCF                 xor     eax, eax
CODE:00470CD1                 pop     edx
CODE:00470CD2                 pop     ecx
CODE:00470CD3                 pop     ecx
CODE:00470CD4                 mov     fs:[eax], edx
CODE:00470CD7                 pop     eax
CODE:00470CD8                 xor     ebx, ebx
CODE:00470CDA                 jmp     short loc_470CE1
CODE:00470CDC ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CODE:00470CDC
CODE:00470CDC loc_470CDC:                             ; DATA XREF: CODE:00470CB8↑o
CODE:00470CDC                 jmp     @System@@HandleAutoException$qqrv ; System::__linkproc__ HandleAutoException(void)
CODE:00470CE1 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CODE:00470CE1
CODE:00470CE1 loc_470CE1:                             ; CODE XREF: CODE:00470CDA↑j
CODE:00470CE1                 mov     eax, ebx
CODE:00470CE3                 pop     edi
CODE:00470CE4                 pop     esi
CODE:00470CE5                 pop     ebx
CODE:00470CE6                 pop     ebp
CODE:00470CE7                 retn    8
CODE:00470CE7 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CODE:00470CEA                 align 4
CODE:00470CEC ; [00000057 BYTES: COLLAPSED FUNCTION Mtsrdm::TMtsDataModule::AS_GetProviderNames(System::OleVariant &). PRESS CTRL-NUMPAD+ TO EXPAND]
CODE:00470D43                 align 4
CODE:00470D44
```

I need to discover the inputs and the algorithm to do my project.
Now My Question is how can I extract a function by knowing its behaviour in IDA Pro with existing code?

Edit1: What I show from the code is an example, and I do not really know which part of code is really responsible for the functionality I am assuming.

Edit2:https://www.delicad.com/dl/FlashPolygons_32bits_en.zip
The link gives the whole  dll which I  want to find the part which draws a line using two points.

Comment: what do you mean by define?

Comment: I edited my question. As I told when you know what a part of code does how can i find that part?

Comment: If you only have IDA without decompiler plugin then the only way is to look at the assembler code, understand what it does instruction by instruction and the write a C program that does the same.

Comment: from your query it appears youare searching for data and notcode calcul is a  string and ida properly gets it for you CODE:00470C9C aCalcul:                                ; DATA XREF: CODE:00470C0F↑o
CODE:00470C9C                 text "UTF-16LE", 'calcul',0  you do nothave code at your search location you might have misunderstood something

Comment: @blabb I think I am not explaining good enough see the edit.

Comment: Sorry your edit does not clarify much if you do not know what you are looking for then maybe you should rewrite the whole dll ??  use ida to list all known exports start converting one by one and in the process rename all the functions in the control flow.

Comment: @blabb For example I know that the code is drawing a line somewhere how can I guess where the code is doing that? I need a general method to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: reversing is a methodology not a guess game look at all the known exports by the dll look at the graphics related imports of the dll  and start narrowing down. if you have the executable that uses this dll and if it is possible to debug it find the entry points to this dll from that executable and break on them and see which import is hit when you draw a line

Comment: Try ask your professor for instructions on how to do it, might be an other way than reverse engineering because it could take months.
In addition, have you ask permissions from delicad to reverse engineering their program? That could be illegal depends on where you from!

Comment: is that a commercial program i dont think any professor will advocate reverse engineering a commercial program for academic reasons you are biting too much more than you can chew  compile a simple sample yourself and practice on it or find suitable practice materials.

Comment: That's the thing, we have questions regarding this and it depends on the jurisdiction, but this is more commentary than an answer.

Comment: @blabb my professor did not give me dll as project it is an example.The goal is to find the way the way to do this.

Comment: @blabb "reverse engineering a commercial program" is very funny maybe We cannot draw a line by having two points and this is high technology.

Comment: @blabb " if you have the executable that uses this dll and if it is possible to debug it find the entry points to this dll from that executable and break on them and see which import is hit when you draw a line"  I think this is what you mean by "reverse engineering commercial program" I think I am not going to do that.

Comment: I found that by checking registers and comparing them with given points I can find out which part of code is responsible for the function.